# Can't work with interop.Exel in .NET 3.0

Tags: c#, mysql, excel-interop

I've developped an application for my internship, I've done it in C# .NET 4.5 with Windows 8 64 bits, full compatible with .NET 4.0.

But in fact, I have to install it on old computers with WinXP 32/64 bits and .NET 3.0 without administrator rights...

So now I'm trying to put my project in .NET 3.0 from .NET 4.0 and I have some problems with that, in my code I have:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

"Office" is underlined with blue.

I also have a error message with "Reference assembly is missing blablabla"
So ok, I go to add references assemblies but... Impossible to add them, I tried all of them but it doesn't change anything...

I'm searching on the web but I can't find a good and clear answer, so I'm there :)

Thanks for all (and to all =P)

Solution:

Downgrade your interop.Excel DLL and add it to your references assemblies.

You'll have this error:
    Impossible to convert type 'object' to 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet'. An explicit conversion exists (cast blablabla)

```
xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets[1];
```

So just change this to this:

```
xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Sheets[1];
```

Comment: you have not added the `reference` in your project section ..try right clicking on `reference-->add Reference`

Comment: I've add it...
It works with 4.5, 4.0 too, and I said that I tried to add it for 3.0 but it failed, that's why I'm here.

Comment: can you try setting the project to `3.5`

Comment: I have the same problem =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to downgrade the version of the office interopt DLL.

Comment: That's an idea, I'll try and I come back :)

Comment: Ok now it works thank you Thibaut :)
I add a office interop excel dll from 2002 =P

Comment: Oooooooooh dear no !
Now I have another problem with that !

Before, I had this:

    Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
    xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets[1];

and    xlWorkBook.Sheets    is underlined in red.

The error message is (translated French to English sry if bad):
    Impossible to convert type 'object' to 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet'. An explicit conversion exists (cast blablabla)

Comment: Ok, aaaaaaaall is ok.

I just had to do this:
    xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Sheets[1];

Thanks to all !

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the code that throw the exception and also put the exception in english.
You can try to cast like this : '((Worksheets) xlWorkBook.Sheets)[0])
Ok you got it :)

Comment: If I've answered your question, can you mark your question answered  ?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to read and write xls files?

If you only want to read and write xlsx files, you can use OpenXML. It would be a full-managed solution for your problem.